# Not all code is shown in the pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles

So I found an example online of how to create a certain figure (tikzpicture). Now I have created the figure in latex, but somehow my Title and section text will not show. I guess this is because I dont have the documentclass to article. But if I have my documentclass is article the figure will not show. How can I solve this?
Below is my code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}


\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\title{Matematisk modellering}
\author{olba_ }
\date{February 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\section{Problem 1}

Givet avståndet $d$ från högtalare och ljudkälla, samt givet högtalarnas positioner, beräkna läget för ljudkällan.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    scale=3,
    >=stealth,
    point/.style = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = 1pt},
    dot/.style   = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = .2pt},
  ]

  % the circle
  \def\rad{1}
  \node (origin) at (0,0) {};


  % triangle nodes: just points on the circle
  \node (n0) at +(60:\rad) [point, label = above:$s$] {};
  \node (n1) at +(-145:\rad) [point, label = below:$r_{1}$] {};
  \node (n2) at +(-45:\rad) [point, label = {below right:$r_{2}$}] {};
  \node (n3) at +(10:\rad) [point, label = {below left:$r_{3}$}] {};

  % triangle edges: connect the vertices, and leave a node at the midpoint
  \draw[->] (n2) -- node (a) [label = {above left:$d_{2}$}] {} (n0);
  \draw[->] (n1) -- node (b) [label = {below right:$d_{1}$}] {} (n0);
  \draw[->] (n3) -- node (c) [label = {above right:$d_{3}$}] {} (n0);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `olba_ ` is strange. Do  you really want an underscore in the name?

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you want to have a real article, with titles and so on. So use the `article` class and then load `tikz` later.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\title{Matematisk modellering}
\author{name here}
\date{February 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\section{Problem 1}

Givet avståndet $d$ från högtalare och ljudkälla, samt givet högtalarnas positioner, beräkna läget för ljudkällan.
\begin{figure*}[h]\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    scale=3,
    >=stealth,
    point/.style = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = 1pt},
    dot/.style   = {draw, circle,  fill = black, inner sep = .2pt},
  ]

  % the circle
  \def\rad{1}
  \node (origin) at (0,0) {};


  % triangle nodes: just points on the circle
  \node (n0) at +(60:\rad) [point, label = above:$s$] {};
  \node (n1) at +(-145:\rad) [point, label = below:$r_{1}$] {};
  \node (n2) at +(-45:\rad) [point, label = {below right:$r_{2}$}] {};
  \node (n3) at +(10:\rad) [point, label = {below left:$r_{3}$}] {};

  % triangle edges: connect the vertices, and leave a node at the midpoint
  \draw[->] (n2) -- node (a) [label = {above left:$d_{2}$}] {} (n0);
  \draw[->] (n1) -- node (b) [label = {below right:$d_{1}$}] {} (n0);
  \draw[->] (n3) -- node (c) [label = {above right:$d_{3}$}] {} (n0);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solved the problem.